# Proper way to render a lot of text with Direct2d in separate thread

Tags: c++, directx, sharpdx, direct2d

I write a program where I need to render a lot of text on the screen, when the user moves the scroll bars or when the size of the window changes, the text must be rerendered, and it takes half a second or more and is very unpleasant to the user.

So the solution I found was that the render would be done in a separate thread, running all the time in the background and when needed, he gets a message and renders everything that is needed.

The problem occurs when the user changes the size of the window by dragging the corner of the window, where then the render thread receives a message to render and before it finishes the render the window resizes again, and this causes the text to stretch because the render is designed for a small width and width is already getting bigger.

At the end a new render is performed and the text looks excellent, but while changing the width of the window the user sees the text stretched and it is very not nice.

On [Direct2D documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d2d1/nn-d2d1-id2d1hwndrendertarget) the behavior is described:

> If EndDraw presents the buffer, this bitmap is stretched to cover the
>   surface where it is presented: the entire client area of the window

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: I have to ask; are you testing an optimized/release build or a unoptimized debug build? Only ever measure performance with optimized builds, as debug builds are focused on providing a good debug experience but (often *severely*) sacrifice performance to do so. There can easily be orders of magnitude differences in performance between the different build types.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I testing an optimized/release build.

Comment: This does not make much sense. Basically you only need to render about one screen of the text at most why would it take half of second or more? Maybe you are applying some fancy styling or rerender a lot of off-screen text somehow? As for presentation, you should look into DXGI.

Comment: @VTT Because the user can zoom 10% and see at once a million characters, each character having an outline, meaning that each character should also render geometry for the outline.

Comment: *see at once a million characters* - even on 4k screen that would leave about 8 pixels per character which makes it worthless. And there typically no need to rerender fancy geometry for each character, you can prerender sprite sheet and then batch them out on the screen.

Comment: @VTT What do you mean _prerender sprite sheet and then batch them out on the screen_?

Comment: I mean you can render each letter used in text into texture representing a sprite sheet and then draw those sprites as textured quads onto screen. Positions of letters and their metrics can be obtained though DirectWrite.

Comment: This question is not specific to Direct2D or rendering from separate thread. You're mixing different issues. First of all EndDraw stretching resulting bitmap is about HwndTarget, and you need to call Resize() on it when window size changes.

Comment: Regarding text rendering performance, like @VTT said you could consider some caching technique instead of rendering same glyphs over and over. For scrolling it's another thing, you don't need to render everything again when you scroll, it should be enough to render+cache newly exposed parts only.